# Share the same Sender Authentication Package across BUs

Tags: marketing-cloud, sender-authentication-package

Our requirement is to send email using the same domain with different local parts from multiple business units. The enterprise BU has the Sender Authenticated Domain value but it is blank in the child BU.

Is it possible to share the same Sender Authentication Package/Domain between multiple business units?

Comment: Yes to IP/Domains, but the actual SAP itself is per BU, I believe. That being said though, I would talk with Support about this. I am fairly confident that you can get it at least mostly spread across your child BUs without requiring new SAPs for each.

Comment: Thanks @Gortonington for your quick response! Will reach out to MC support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, you can:

> In certain scenarios, SAP can be shared across multiple accounts in
>   the same environment. Create a support case to review your specific
>   scenario. Reference the MIDs involved and the original SAP
>   configuration case number in your support case.

Reference:

[Help](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_sap.htm&type=5)

Comment: This really helps. I will raise a case with MC support.

Comment: No worries. Please consider marking this as an answer ..

Comment: Update: MC support copied the SAP from our enterprise BU to a child BU. It worked.

Comment: @RachidMamai - the help link appears to be outdated. Is this the correct one? https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_sender_authentication_package.htm&type=5